# Drupal contrib module for attaching an Image to a Vocabulary

Tags: drupal

Does anyone know of a drupal (6) module for associating an image with a vocabulary? (similar to the way Taxonomy image does for terms)

I've seen this post on d.o http://drupal.org/node/533282 (but there is no answer - and it's not what I want anyway)

Thanks, Dan

Comment: Where would you like that image to show up? In node forms and on the taxonomy/term/% page i guess?

Comment: I wouldn't really have minded where it showed up on a default site. Just so long as it was available to theme. In the end I just hard-coded a page since the vocabs on this site are unlikley to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cheeky solution I would suggest is create a new vocabulary called `vocab-images`, which will `contain names of all the vocabularies in the site as its tags`. Then use the `Taxonomy image` module to associate with images.

And wherever you want to display the image, use the custom code which will show the image for the `tag from vocab-images`, that is `same as the vocabulary being viewed`.

This sounds confusing, but give it a try and i think this might work out easily.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I suppose the same trick could work using a new content type "vocab-images"; with an imagefield and a cck field that matches the vocab name/id.


Unfortunately I haven't got time to test it out now (As commented above I solved my immediate problem). This sounds like a winner though.